# Testing Alarms for a Chrome/browser extension

Tags: javascript, testing, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension that uses alarms quite heavily. I want to create test suite, but to do this effectively, I'd need to be able to simulate changing the time as far as the browser sees it, so that I can test alarms firing in certain conditions. What is the nicest/easiest way to do this?

Comment: [Change system time for UNIX process?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14601316)

Comment: @wOxxOm - nice idea but for one thing I'm using Windows, for another it might not work for all cases I want to test.